# Серверное время на Php Js

Tags: php, javascript, время

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся с проблемой: при длительном использовании отстает время (в течении первой минуты уже заметно).
Подскажите как исправить.

```
<?php
```

$timefin = '08:43:40';
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
?>

```js
var hours = <? php echo date("H"); ?> ;
var min = <? php echo date("i"); ?> ;
var sec = <? php echo date("s"); ?> ;
var finaltime = "<?php echo $timefin ?>";

function display() {
  sec += 1;
  if (sec >= 60) {
    min += 1;
    sec = 0;
  }
  if (min >= 60) {
    hours += 1;
    min = 0;
  }
  if (hours >= 24)
    hours = 0;

  if (sec < 10)
    sec2display = "0" + sec;
  else
    sec2display = sec;

  if (min < 10)
    min2display = "0" + min;
  else
    min2display = min;

  if (hours < 10)
    hour2display = "0" + hours;
  else
    hour2display = hours;

  time = hour2display + ":" + min2display + ":" + sec2display;

  if (time == finaltime) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'response.php?',
        data: 'name=Andrew',
        success: function(data) {
          $('#show').html(data);
        }
      });
    });
  }
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = hour2display + ":" + min2display + ":" + sec2display;
  setTimeout("display();", 1000);
}
display();
```

```html
<b id="seconds">0</b>
<div id="show"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таймеры в JS не точные. `setTimeout(..., 1000)` не идеально равен секунде.

Неплохой вариант – вызывать функцию показа времени много раз в секунду. Внутри считать разницу между текущим временем и заданным.

```js
//var finaltime = "<?php echo $timefin ?>"; // timestamp
var finaltime = Math.floor((new Date(2016,5,30,12,0,0)).getTime()/1000);
var timerId = window.setInterval( display, 100);
var el = document.getElementById("seconds");

function display() {
  var seconds = Math.floor((finaltime - (new Date()).getTime()/1000))
    ,minutes
    ,hours
    ,days
  ;
  
  if (seconds <= 0) {
 window.clearInterval( timerId);
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'response.php?',
  data: 'name=Andrew',
  success: function(data) {
   $('#show').html(data);
  }
 });
 return;
  }

  days = Math.floor(seconds/86400);
  seconds = seconds % 86400;
  hours = zeropad( Math.floor( seconds / 3600));
  seconds = seconds % 3600;
  minutes = zeropad( Math.floor( seconds / 60));
  seconds = zeropad( seconds % 60);
  el.innerHTML = days + ' д., ' + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}


function zeropad(n) {
 return n < 10 ? '0'+n : n.toString();
}
```

```html
<b id="seconds">0</b>
<div id="show"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то что мне нужно! Но как сделать что бы время брало с сервера а не компьютера?